# I'm a noob and I'm used to writing reusable code with methods. How do I write the same kind of code with Activities?

Tags: android

I'm writing my first android app, and it's going very well so far, but my code is getting obtuse and I'd like to reorganize it in a way that allows me to reuse portions, and add things more easily.

Based on my previous experience writing simple command line programs that call methods, this is how I THINK I should organize my code:

(some code in MainActivity)

- Call a void method of the object DoStuff:

  - Launch Activity1 and write some values to SharedPreferences file, THEN
  - Launch Activity2 and write some values to SharedPreferences file, THEN
  - continue running code from MainActivity

Right now Activity1 and Activity2 both launch at the same time. Is there a different way I should be writing/organizing my code? I guess I'm trying to do thing with Activities that I'm used to doing with methods. But I'm aware that my thinking might be wrong on this. I hope this makes sense.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Activity`s are classes and therefore can have whatever methods you wish.

Comment: "Right now Activity1 and Activity2 both launch at the same time." What do you mean by this? You cannot launch two activities at the same time. Since an activity occupies the entire screen, you can only have one at a time.

Comment: I think you need to back up to a little higher level view. Think about the screens in your app and how the user interacts with them. It will help if you edit your question to describe the flow of your app. Feel free to post mockups of the screens to help us visual how your UI looks.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of Activities is wrong. Activities do have methods that you can very well use.

An Activity is basically one screen that you see in your app. It can be started, stopped, resumed, etc. You can have different screens shown in one Activity (e. g. with Fragments).

If for example you have a list of notes in one Activity, you could have the detail of one note shown in another DetailActivity.

Only in rare cases, for example if you want to check on startup what Activity to show you could have another activity that does not have a layout but only does some checks and launches another one.

In each of your activities you can have methods to execute what you want on user interaction. Of course this can also go into other classes.

I would recommend you to start with a basic Android tutorial to gain a better understanding of the concepts.